# Run code after objects list is created to alter them

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I want to run code on the objecs list of a `ToManyField` after the objects are generated.

I have the following code:

```
class ResourceB(ModelResource):
    x = ForeignKey...
    y = ForeignKey...
    z = ForeignKey...

    def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
        # Do some altering here


class ResourceA(ModelResource):
    b = ToManyField(ResourceB, 'b', full=True)

    ...
```

When I try to access the URI of `ResourceA`, I see that the `alter_list_data_to_serialize` is not called at all.
Why?
How can I alter objects of `ToManyField` in one place after they are created (Without `dehydrate`)?

Comment: Is your indentation like your example?

Comment: I had some formatting issues. Now it is.

Comment: If you want to alter data on update and create you ought to be using `alter_deserialized_list_data`. But maybe I am not understanding your question.